# Excel How do I test a cell against multiple cells and return a formatted value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to create a formula in Excel 2016 to format a cell based on another cell's value.  I am trying use the value in Page1 D30 to format another cell, page 2 A2, based on the criteria in the page 1 N series to format the page 2 A2 with the page 1 M series.

Sorry for the confusion this is a bit difficult to explain. in simple terms I need Page 2 A2 to look like a value in Page 1 M based on the values in Page 1 D30 compared to Page 1 N.

The code I have tried is:

```
=IFS('Chart Reference Page'!D30>=85%, =D27,84%>='Chart Reference Page'!D30>=70%, =D28, 69%>='Chart Reference Page'!D30>=55%, =D29,'Chart Reference Page'!D30<55%, =D30, TRUE, "")
```

The formatting that it needs to take on is a text value within a colored cell (D27:D30) and the values that are being evaluated are %s.

Again sorry this is hard to explain!

Comment: Formulas will not copy or change the formatting, it will only return values.

Comment: is there a way to mirror formatting?  IE if I were to assign a value 1-4 based on the category then create a custom conditional format to mirror a cell?

Comment: If you only have 4 options then you can use four rules in custom formatting based on the value returned.  But it will be anchored on the value returned and not the formatting of the cell from which the value was found.